# Ошибка PostgresException: 23502 при попытке добавить запись в БД в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Делаю небольшой проект на ASP.NET Core 3.1. В качестве бд используется PostgresSQL, в качестве ORM - Entity Framework Core 3. Есть две модели - Country и Company, связанные отношением "один-к-одному". Есть форма, через которую пользователь добавляет объект Country в бд - всё работает. Соответственно, есть форма для добавления объекта Company.В ней определен тег  для выбора объекта Country. При POST запросе вылетает ошибка: PostgresException: 23502: нулевое значение в столбце "CountryId" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL. Много всего перепробовал, всё также вылетает ошибка.В чём может быть проблема?Почему CountryId null, хотя он не должен быть таковым?[image: Форма][image: Сообщение об ошибке]

Comment: Как вы эту country считываете на бекенде во время post запроса?

Comment: В контроллере определён  метод, который помечен атрибутом HttpPost, и который принимает объект типа Company, затем добавляет в контекст.Напрямую метод не принимает Country, как я читал, привязчик ASP.NET Core должен сам считать подходящие данные и создать объект для последующей POST обработки....

Comment: зне описывайте код текстом, добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: Извините, добавил скриншот.